# Android studio getting crashed when gradle is build on mac

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build

I am working on `android studio` from one year But i can't face this type of problem. What i am doing is **adding a dependency of support library** in app `build.gradle` and then sync the project.

`Gradle` build running is started in background and then after some time studio is automatically crashed. There is no error or logs are found for crashes. And **if I removed the dependency from gradle it works properly**. *I also restarted the machine and having an latest update of studio* but it can't fixed the problem. Thanks in advance for any help.

Here is my app level build.gradle file. I am adding compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0' library in my project

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
   compileSdkVersion 23
   buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId ""
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.isseiaoki:simplecropview:1.0.9'
    compile "com.mixpanel.android:mixpanel-android:4.8.0"
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.10.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Plz show you gradle file, without it no one can help :)

Comment: Studio crashed!!! report this to google then. And please also share your app level and project level build.gradle.

Comment: @Alexander and drulabs, Here i posted my app level build.gradle file

Comment: Try to compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'

Comment: don't know but after getting update of java and support library fixed my problem. Thanks @Alexander.